# Is it possible with Delphi VCL styles to change the form caption (non client) font at runtime?

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have looked at RRUZ's awesome VCL Style Utils, and in the VCL Styles source, and I can't see any way to change the nonclient area caption *font* face (name), or color, or size, at runtime.

Is there a way? Or do I need to subclass `TNCControls` and override some paint code?

Update: I can change the font by modifying the style in the bitmap style designer, but that only lets you set the font once and never change it at runtime.

Comment: You can change this in the "Bitmap Style Designer". As far as changing it from within your Delphi code, I'm not sure. Looking now, I can see in `Objects > Form > Image > Title > Caption` the properties has a `Font` you can change.

Comment: that would let me modify the style itself to always use a different one, but I'd like to actually change the color and the font face at runtime.

Comment: You can change a style at run time. There are quite a few tutorials out there.

Comment: Warren, have you managed to change the form caption font at runtime somehow? @Dsm could you link some of them? I was searching quite a lot but haven't found one. Thank you!

Comment: No or I would have answered my own question.  I think that the most sensible option would be to create a custom style that has the fonts I want, for a one time font change.  And if not that, then some subclassing of VCL classes would be necessary.

Comment: And by the way Victoria, if you change a style at runtime, be sure the style is not used by anything else other than that form caption, or you'll be doing things with huge side effects.